# Nesting under IndexRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I wrote an app to teach myself Flux and React Routers, and I'm getting stuck on nested routes. I have a list of parks, and when you click on one of the parks, it brings up a show page. This works fine if I have my routes nested like this:

```
const appRouter = (
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ AppIndex }/>
      <Route path="parks/:parkId" component={ ParkShow }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

But, that's not what I want. I want to show information about the park that's clicked on in the AppIndex page. This is what I have to achieve that goal:

```
const appRouter = (
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ AppIndex }>
        <Route path="parks/:parkId" component={ ParkShow }/>
      </IndexRoute>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

I get - "Warning: [react-router] Location "parks/2" did not match any routes"

And - "Warning: [react-router] Location "/parks/2" did not match any routes"

Comment: One solution is to add the AppIndex component to the top of my ParkShow component. That gives me the behavior I'm looking for, but it seems hacky to me though. I feel like there must be a way to get this behavior from the routes themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route inside a index page is a wrong way

```
const appRouter = (
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute component={ AppIndex }/>
      <Route path="parks/:parkId" component={ ParkShow }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

Above one is the only correct way
Design your app in such a way move the contents of AppIndex to APP  and use this.props.children in the APP component.
You should either be showing Appindex or the ParkShow

Comment: This doesn't produce my desired behavior.

My desired behavior is for the content in AppIndex to show up when visiting the homepage, and to persist to ParkShow, but to not persist to other pages in the app, while I want the content in the App component to persist throughout the app.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276787/how-to-nest-react-routes-in-homepage