# How to nest React Routes in homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out how to properly nest routes inside the homepage. Here's my Router:

```
var appRouter = (
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ Navbar }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Homepage }/>
      <Route path="items" component={ Homepage }>
        <Route path=":item" component={ ItemShow }/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="nothome" component={ NotHome }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

Having an IndexRoute and Route that both point to Homepage doesn't seem optimal, but it gives me the behavior I'm looking for. Here's my whole project (I wrote this just to illustrate this point).

```
//React
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
//Router
var ReactRouter = require('react-router')
var Router = ReactRouter.Router
var Route = ReactRouter.Route
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory
var Link = ReactRouter.Link

var items = [1, 2]

var Navbar = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Link to="/"><h1>Navbar</h1></Link>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Homepage = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>This is the homepage</h2>
        <ItemList/>
        <Link to="/nothome">Another page</Link>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var ItemList = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <ul>
        {items.map( item => {
          return <Item key={item} id={item}></Item>
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
})

var Item = React.createClass({
  handleClick(){
    hashHistory.push("items/" + this.props.id)
  },
  render(){
    return(
      <li onClick={this.handleClick}>Item {this.props.id}</li>
    )
  }
})

var ItemShow = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        You clicked on item {this.props.params.item}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var NotHome = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <h2>This is not the homepage</h2>
    )
  }
})

var appRouter = (
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ Navbar }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Homepage }/>
      <Route path="items" component={ Homepage }>
        <Route path=":item" component={ ItemShow }/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="nothome" component={ NotHome }/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
  ReactDOM.render(appRouter, document.getElementById("root"))
})
```

[image: React Routes Nested In Homepage]

Another option would be to put a Homepage component at the top of my ItemShow component and not nest the routes, but that seems just as bad if not worse.

It seems like there must be a preferable way to get this behavior. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for your code, it seems that you don't really need to have this "items" route, since both "/" and "/items" render the same component (`<Homepage>`).

So, if you want to avoid having two "`Homepage`" declaration, you can *redirect* your user to "items", whenever they go to "/". You can do that by using [`<IndexRedirect>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.5.2/docs/API.md#indexredirect) or [`<Redirect>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.5.2/docs/API.md#redirect) or [`onEnter`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.5.2/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) hook.

More information about the hook:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.5.2/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects

If you really want to be able to access those two routes pointing to the **same** component, maybe you don't have to change anything. But, in your case, I would have a "Homepage" (even with some dummy info) and a "Items Homepage", and it would avoid the "Homepage" repetition.

BTW, just as a tip, I would rename your `<NavBar>` to "`<App>`" or something like that, since it would be better to understand your code!

Comment: Thanks! I actually originally named the top component App, and someone recommended moving my index content there, so I changed the name to Navbar, ironically, for clarity.

My goal is definitely NOT to have two routes pointing to the same component, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I just want the user to be able to visit the homepage and add stuff to that homepage.

I was thinking about just putting a redirect in my Rails controller, but I figured there had to be a way to do this more beautifully with React. Looks like IndexRedirect is the way to go!

Comment: Does IndexRedirect do the same thing as IndexRoute in terms of populating {this.props.children} of it's parent component?

Comment: @WylliamJudd no, Redirect and IndexRedirect as well don't populate `this.props.children`, they just "move" your user to another route, and that route will populate that.

Comment: I'll have to experiment. Without IndexRoute, App doesn't populate this.props.children on page visit. As long as they get populated, that's all I meant.